# Make an internal NVME drive bootable

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux, bootloader, nvme

I’m installing UEFI arch Linux using a live usb on a NVMe-drive laptop. I got up until disk partitioning when I saw that I could not flag any partitions in the NVME drive as bootable. The only partitions I can flag as bootable we’re in the /dev/sda usb drive which is formatted as dos while my ssd is formatted as gpt.

One solution might be to format the ssd as dos or to create a bootable logical volume with LVM but I can’t get any of this to work yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Bootable' flag **is not used** in UEFI boot process. The firmware uses different ways to find where to boot from – normally it looks for the specific partition GUID if one is stored in the firmware's NVRAM (the UEFI boot menu), and if there's no NVRAM data yet, then it'll search for partitions with the correct *type*.

(The EFI System Partition has the type ID `{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}` on GPT disks, also known as `EF00` if you're using 'gdisk'. Similarly, on MBR disks, type `EF` indicates the EFI System Partition.)